# How should I rectify wrong information on my resume, when I already received the offer?

Tags: resume, job-offer, hiring-process, background-check, mistakes

I received an offer from a company via a competitive coding contest. The information that was conveyed through my resume was slightly wrong by mistake. Instead of having an overall experience of 3.5 years, it was showing an experience of 2.5 years.

1. How should I rectify this wrong information with my employer?
2. Does this wrong information affect my offered position and CTC?

Comment: How was it wrong? For example, did you write "Job X: Jan 2014 - Jun 2016" when you should have written "Job X: Jan 2014 - Jun 2017"?

Comment: What do you mean by CTC?

Comment: It was like "Job X: November 2015 - December 2016", however it should be written like "Job X: November 2014 - December 2015".

Comment: CTC means the "Cost to Company" or Annual Salary.

Comment: Is "Job X" your *only* relevant experience?  This looks like ~1 year of experience either way, just the years are wrong.

Comment: Aman CTC Is far more than just your salary it should take account of taxes cost of offices/equipment

Comment: In Resume, Job X: November 2015 - December 2016, then Job Y: January 2017 - December 2017. Job Y was a self funded startup venture.

Comment: In Reality, Job X: November 2014 - December 2015, then Job Y: January 2016 - December 2017

Comment: @Neuromancer, Annual Salary was extreme simplification. I also wrote "Cost to Company" for the same

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't rectify this at all.

You basically tell them that you had one year more experience than they thought, but on the other hand you are not even focused enough to get important data on your CV right. They probably didn't take notice of this employment time at all, because it would have meant a one year employment gap which you would have been asked about, so overall this will look negative for you.

Since nobody can accuse you of cheating (the information shown was less good than the correct information), I wouldn't say anything. If you have an offer, either nobody will care, or will care about you making mistakes in important documents.

PS. Nobody will increase your pay after they made an offer. One year experience vs. so unfocused that a person cant even get their CV right - at best this cancels out. It definitely doesnt make you look good.

Comment: I completely agree, but showing more experience may increase the CTC. Do you agree on that?

Comment: I rectified the issue with the HR, there was no issue from there side. Sometimes, it's better to communicate than hide.